# Adding Prerequisites using InstallShield  2010

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010

I am very new to Installshield 2010. I have created a basic MSI setup for my application.
I need to check a few prerequisites for my application those are as below.

1. Microsoft frame work 3.5 with SP1.
2. Sql Express 2005.
3. Visual C++ redistributable

If any of the above things are not installed before means, I have to install while installing my application.

Can anyone guide me How I can install all these prerequisites before I installing my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at "Setup Prerequisites" and "Feature Prerequistes"  They are the same except that the former are installed by setupe.exe before calling your MSI and the latter are installed by setup.exe (conditionally) after your feature selection and prior to the execution of the execute sequence in your msi.

If you go for the former, you probably also want to author AppSearch/System Search and Launch Conditions to block your MSI in case the user doesn't enter through the setup.exe.

InstallShield has predefined prereqs ( .PRQ's ) for each of those although I will caution you to atleast use SQL 2005 SP3 as there is a nasty bug in SP2 that can blue screen an XP machine.  I'd actually really consider going with SQL 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Also found more info here in this page: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/IHelpSetPrereqCustom.htm

Answer (score 0):

This one took me quite a while to find, hopefully I'll save you some time.

If you just want to force your user to have some applications installed (e.g. 'Visual C++ redistributable') or some specific configuration (e.g. specific Windows version/ reg value etc.)
You can use 'Behavior and Logic -> System Search' add the search for what you need (file/folders/registry entries/ini files values/XML file values),
On "What do you want to do with the value?" dialog select Store the values in the property and use the property in an Install Condition".

This will cause the Search to be executed when your installation package starts and will display an error popup to the user saying what ever message you've entered for the condition.

Few notes:
- If you're looking for a x64bit registry entry - mark the "Search the 64-bit portion of the Registry" check box.
- Did not find a way to edit the Condition once created, when tried to edit it it just lets me see and change the search parameters, but for the condition it only allows to enter it from scratch; as a workaround you can save the project as XML file (Installation Information -> General Information -> Project File Format) and edit the XML externally.

Good luck.